# <BEA-160228> AppMerge failed to merge your application

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

Got this dreaded `<BEA-160228>` & ToolFailureException when deploying spring-boot 2.x app on weblogic 12.1.x multiple times. Solved one with some package guesswork in `<wls:prefer-application-packages>`, but got another again each time we add new dependencies.

I know there's some thread asking this already, but it's usually very specific to each dependencies, i need different perspective on this.

**Is there a way to debug/analyze what happened inside weblogic AppMerge process?** 
So we could exactly pinpoint what library caused this. 
I've tried enabling debug deployment options, but didn't see any clue on the logs

[image]

Comment: Server's log files should give info about deployment failure.
Anyway, you can also "merge" yourserf the application before deploying it in WebLogic.
This can be done with ANT ant the task appmerge (weblogic.ant.taskdefs.j2ee.AppMergeTask) Read this [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24368/libraries.htm#WLPRG348) for details.